# Select Data based on Sum of another columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table with Data as

```
RowIndex    Id  TicketCount
 1          23  1
 2          25  2
 3           3  1
 4          14  1
 5          16  1
 6          18  1
 7           1  1
 8           6  1
 9          15  1 ===> at this row the sum of Ticket Count is 10
10          22  1
11          27  1
12          24  1
13          26  2
14           9  1
15          19  1
```

From this Data I want to Select All Records where The Sum of Ticket Count will be equal to 10(user input value)

In the Given data I want to Select all Records till Row Index 9.
Output should be:

```
RowIndex    Id  TicketCount
 1          23  1
 2          25  2
 3           3  1
 4          14  1
 5          16  1
 6          18  1
 7           1  1
 8           6  1
 9          15  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have the cumulative sum function.  I implement it using a correlated subquery:

```
select RowIndex, Id, TicketCount
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(TicketCount)
              from t t2
              where t2.RowIndex <= t.RowIndex
             ) as cumTicketCount
      from t
     ) t
where cumTicketCount <= 10;
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can phrase this using a window function:

```
select RowIndex, Id, TicketCount
from (select t.*, sum(TicketCount) over (order by RowIndex) as CumTicketCount
      from t
     ) t
where cumTicketCount <= 10;
```

Comment: In Oracle, you could also use a LAG function.

Comment: @Randy . . . In Oracle (for which this question is not tagged), I would simply use the cumulative sum function.  As I would in Postgres and DB2 -- other databases that support it.

Comment: Aren't the windowing functions ` over (order by RowIndex)` older than SQL 2012?

Comment: @xanatos . . . The windowing functions came in SQL Server 2005 (I think), but not the full syntax.  In particular, the cumulative functions are not available until 2012.  So, `sum(xxx) over (partition by yyy)` is supported, but not `sum(xxx) over (partition by yyy order by zzz)` until 2012.

Comment: I see in the msdn... in 2012 they removed the limitation on `order by`. Before it was "not for aggregate functions"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using recursive CTE:

```
WITH RCTE AS 
(
  SELECT *, TicketCount AS Total 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE RowIndex = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.*, r.Total + t.TicketCount 
  FROM RCTE r
  INNER JOIN Table1 t ON r.RowIndex + 1 = t.RowIndex
  WHERE r.Total + t.TicketCount <= 10 --your input value
)
SELECT * FROM RCTE
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6cb78/1)**